# MP3 File through ARDUINO

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, arduino-pro-mini, audio

Hey question is that it is possible to play MP3 file in arduino without changing it into .wav file if possible ,then your suggestions are welcome 
Thanks

Comment: Yes, with an MP3 shield.

Comment: The UNO doesn't have the processing power to decode MP3.

Comment: Ok i will try for this ,thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little device is really good and easy to set up.
https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1121.html

You can use a pin and set it to ground with a resistor between to change songs if you don't need something fancy.